# how to change field‘s initial value using javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I'm trying to mock some services in my developing env. The serviceFactory code is something like:

```
public class ApiFacadeImpl implements ApiFacade {
private OneService oneService = null;
    public OneService getOneService(){
        if(oneService==null) {//some initialization steps }
        return oneService;
    }
}
```

I know this factory is not well coded and designed. However I can't modify its code.
my idea is to change the bytecode, so I can redefine it to something like:

```
public class ApiFacadeImpl implements ApiFacade {
private OneService oneService = new MyMockOneService();
    ....
}
```

**My 1st is:
is this possible using javassist?  And how?**

Since I can't find anything like reinitialize a field using javassist using google, I tried myself by deleting it and recreate it:

```
        CtField oneServiceField = cc.getDeclaredField("oneService");
    cc.removeField(oneServiceField);
    CtField f = CtField.make(String.format("private %s %s=new %s();",
            oneServiceField.getType().getName(), "oneService",
            mockClass.getCanonicalName()), cc);
    cc.addField(f);
    cc.toClass();
```

then I got exception:

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid length 99 in LocalVariableTable in class file com/Test
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1051)
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:994)
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:952)
at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1079)
```

**My 2nd question is why this exception? Which step disobey java class's definition? And when I delete the field does javassist help to delete field reference in:**

```
public OneService getOneService(){
        if(oneService==null) {//some initialization steps }
        return oneService;
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What is mockClass.getCanonicalName()?

Comment: What is your javassist version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question #1, yes, you can achieve this via modify `ApiFacadeImpl`'s constructor. Remember to use `CtConstructor#insertAfter` to append the assignment statement.

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass factoryClass = pool.getCtClass("ServiceFactory");
CtConstructor constructor = factoryClass.getDeclaredConstructor(null);
String setMockStatement = String.format("service = new %s();",
        MockServiceImpl.class.getCanonicalName());
constructor.insertAfter(setMockStatement);
factoryClass.toClass();
new ServiceFactory().getService().say();
```

I tried the way you proposed. However, it didn't work. After some debuggings, I found that if we remove a field, it won't remove the initialization statement for this field. If we add the field again with our expected initialization statement, it will executed before the original initialization statement. So the `service` field is assigned to `MockServiceImpl` at first and then assigned to `null`. Please refer to the following javassist bug.

[javassist-3.14.0-GA - Problm in default initializer of class variables when they are deleted and created using removeField and addField, CtField.make](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-140)

For question #2, I am not sure why this happens. What is your javassist version? How does your mockClass look like? Could you please refer to the following javassist bug?

[Javassist causes java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid length 561 in LocalVariableTable in class file](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-99)

Comment: lhuang, thanks for the answer. Actually the mockclass just extends OneServuce:  public class MockClass extends OneService {//nothing}. I'll check the reference links. I use javassist-3.11.0.GA btw.

Comment: OneService is an interface or a class?